# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

User Slice

```
import {createAsyncThunk, createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import {auth} from "@/lib/firebase.ts";

....

export const createUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/createUser',
  async({ email, password }: ICredential)=> {
    console.log(email, password)
    const data = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    return data.user.email;
  }
)

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(createUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.isError = false;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(createUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user.email = action.payload;
        state.isLoading = false;
      })
      .addCase(createUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.user.email = null;
        state.isError = true;
        state.error = action.error.message!;
      })
  }
});

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Sign Up page on submit

```
const onSubmit = async(data: SignupFormInputs) => {
    await dispatch(createUser({ email: data.email, password: data.password }));
};
```

I am using Firebase to authenticate. On submit, I want to use createUser to create a user at the firebase. But it is giving an error at create user

Comment: Can you give a full error?
The reason could be data.user.email

Also do you get anything in devtools network tab?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
    at reducer (createReducer.ts:251:25)
    at reducer (createSlice.ts:372:14)
    at onSubmit (SignUpForm.tsx:32:20)
    at createFormControl.ts:1069:15

Comment: And there is nothing in the network tab.

Comment: Check if `auth` object exists also check if `email` and `password` exist

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include the complete error message and accompanying error stacktrace, and to include a more complete [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

One of the defined typescript interface per example ICredential, has a property type that couldn't be null, check which typescript interface has this value and try to fill it or to make nullable.